# PromptChar for vb.NET's MaskedTextBox to display prompt as mm:ss

Tags: vb.net

I can able to use PromptChar property of mask-textbox by adding it programmatically but I cant able to get display PromptChar as "MM:SS" I written following code.

```
Mtxt = New MaskedTextBox
Mtxt.Name = "txtRTime" & IND
Mtxt.Font = New Font("arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
Mtxt.Visible = True
Mtxt.Height = 30
Mtxt.Width = 110
Mtxt.MaxLength = 4
Mtxt.Mask = "00:00"
Mtxt.PromptChar = "MM,SS" 'here is my code but it gives o/p as MM:MM instead of 'MM:SS'
Mtxt.Top = 90
Mtxt.Left = 130
Mtxt.ShortcutsEnabled = False
```

how to encounter this problem....
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no solution. If you had `Option Strict On` then that code wouldn't even compile because, as the name suggests, `PromptChar` is type `Char`, not type `String`. In your case, that `String` is implicitly converted to type `Char` by dropping al but the first character. A `MaskedTextBox` only displays one prompt character; the same character in every fillable location. You can provide a prompt string like that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for help but how can i pass string in promptChar?

Comment: Oops! That last sentence should have been "You CAN'T provide a prompt string like that".  That was the point of my comment.  What you want to do is not possible.  The `MaskedTextBox` control does not work that way.

Comment: `PromptChar` has `Char` type (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.promptchar(v=vs.110).aspx)), it's not applicable to provide string on that property. Use [`Mask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx) property to define format string instead.

Comment: so how can i achieve this with using mask  textbox is there any other way to do it......

Comment: You can look at `DateTimePicker` or handling `OnKeyPress` event on your own to avoid illegal characters (except numeric values and time separator). But AFAIK you can't set prompt character more than one for masking purpose.

Comment: sorry @TetsuyaYamamoto The problem is i cant use DateTimePicker I have to do this using textbox itself.